# Django: Having trouble setting up Many-To-One model

Tags: python, django

I am building a site where users can upload reviews of burgers. They can also rate the burgers on a number of criteria. I then want to make a landing page for each burger place with information from the reviews. I think I set my model up right, but I am having trouble querying my database.

My models.py is:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Review(models.Model):
    RATINGS = (
    (1, '1'),
    (2, '2'),
    (3, '3'),
    (4, '4'),
    (5, '5'),
    )

    place = models.ForeignKey(Place)
    burger = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date = models.DateField(default = datetime.now)
    bun = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, choices=RATINGS)
    toppings = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, choices=RATINGS)
    meat = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, choices=RATINGS)
    comments = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    #photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.burger
```

So now I want to create a landing page for each burger place using the information from each review. Like "average bun rating here is 5." How would I query all the reviews and get information like that on a page? I was able to set up a simple landing page that listed the number of reviews about the place, but I can't figure out how to do more than that.

views.py:

```
def index(request):

    context = RequestContext(request)

    place_list = Place.objects.all()

    context_dict = {'places': place_list}

    return render_to_response('index.html', context_dict, context)
```

index.html template:

```
{% for place in places %}
<li><a href="/burgers/place/{{ place.url }}">{{ place.name }}</a> | {{place.review_set.count}}</li>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the reviews on the landing page, you already know the place object. So you can do something like this:

```
place = Place.objects.get(name=place_to_land)
reviews = Review.objects.filter(place=place)
```

Now you have a queryset of reviews which can be rendered on the html page

EDIT:

There are multiple ways of calculating the average rating. Either you can do it in the app or at the DB:

In App:

```
count, rating = 0, 0
for review in reviews:
    count += 1
    rating += review.bun
if count:
   av_rating = rating/count
```

At DB:

```
reviews = Review.objects.filter(place=place).aggregate(Avg('bun'))
```

Comment: What if I want to show the average bun rating on the home page next to the place? How can I run a calculation on the review data associated with every place?

Comment: Updated the answer have a look!

Comment: When you say "At DB" do you mean in the Place model? And In App is that in my index view?

Comment: No not the model but this would trigger a query on the database and give your the results where when I say the application you are right its generally done in the views